# Is it possible to describe a function of: (any-arity => 1-arity)?

Tags: scala, currying

I'd like to be able to pass in a function to a class such that the function always returns a Boolean, but the number of arguments can be variable.

This is actually what I'm working with right now:

```
/**
  * Template class for any SecureSocial SecuredAction.
  */
class SomeAction[T](
    isSuccessful: (SecuredRequest[AnyContent], T) => Boolean, 
    success: Result, 
    failure: Result) extends SecureSocial {

      def toReturn = SecuredAction(WithProvider("google")) {
        implicit request => if (isSuccessful(request)) success else failure
      }

}
```

I'd like the `isSuccessful` argument to be a function that takes at least one argument of type `SecuredRequest[AnyContent]` and a zero or more arguments after that. Sometimes I'll pass in a function that only needs the `request` object, and sometimes I'll pass in a function that needs the `request` object and some other parameters.

After [seeing this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353810/1708136) I looked at currying, which is [the practice of transforming a multiple-argument function into a single-argument function that will return a function if any more arguments are needed](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying). This sounds like it can solve my problem, but after reading up on the [difference between partially applied functions and currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309501/scala-currying-vs-partially-applied-functions), I'm starting to think not? It looks like there is still a set number of eventual arguments...

I suppose successful currying would go like so:

```
class SomeAction[T](
    isSuccessful : ((SecuredRequest[AnyContent])(T) => Boolean) ,  // ERROR
    ... ) ... { ... }
```

This definitely isn't the right syntax.

or

```
class SomeAction[T](
    isSuccessful : (SecuredRequest[AnyContent] => Boolean) , 
    ... ) ... { ... }
```

with something done to `isSuccessful` in `toReturn` to uncurry the passed function.

### Multiple questions that may lead me to the answer:

- Is there some particular syntax for describing curried functions I don't know about?
- Or I'd have a type `(SecuredRequest[AnyContent] => Boolean)` function, but do some sort of uncurrying on the `isSuccessful(request)` call?

Thanks for reading; I guess I'm just looking for uncurrying examples.

Comment: Why not have your caller do that? If you ask for a function `SecuredRequest[AnyContent] => Boolean`, the caller can take care of partially applying any of the other arguments. It's not like you'd know what to pass in anyway, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using variable length argument in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079845/using-variable-length-argument-in-scala)

Comment: Thanks @Myserious Dan ! Yeah that solved my problem ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
/**
  * Template class for any SecureSocial SecuredAction that involves using user information.
  * @param isSuccessful: SecuredRequest[AnyContent] => Boolean
  */
class UserReqAction(
  isSuccessful: (SecuredRequest[AnyContent] => Boolean),
  success: Result, failure: Result) extends SecureSocial {
  def toReturn = SecuredAction(WithProvider("google")) {
    implicit request => if (isSuccessful(request)) success else failure
  }
}

/**
  * Template class for any SecureSocial SecuredAction that does not use user information.
  * @param isSuccessful: SecuredRequest[AnyContent] => Boolean
  */
class UserNotReqAction(isSuccessful: () => Boolean,
                       success: Result, failure: Result) extends SecureSocial {
  def toReturn = SecuredAction(WithProvider("google")) {
    implicit request => if (isSuccessful()) success else failure
  }
}

// not curried example
def makeNewThing = new UserReqAction(
  userOp.createThing,
  Ok(Json.toJson(Json.obj("success" -> true, "msg" -> "Thing successfully created"))),
  BadRequest("failed to create Thing")).toReturn

// curried example
def editThing(param1: _, param2: _, etc) = new UserReqAction(
  userOp.updateThing(param1, param2, etc), // this is the currying
  Ok(Json.toJson(Json.obj("success" -> true, "msg" -> "Thing successfully edited"))),
  BadRequest("failed to edit Thing")).toReturn

def updateThing(param1: _, param2: _, etc)(request: SecuredRequest[AnyContent] ) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a method `f` of type `(A*)B`, then eta-expanded `f _` is just `Seq[A] => B`.

Inside of `f`, the repeated parameter has type `Seq[A]` anyway, so it makes sense.

There's a famous ticket:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4176

It's famous for the immediately deprecated option -Yeta-expand-keeps-star.

Here is an example of a method that takes a function with a star on the left of the arrow and invokes it.

So if by "any-arity" you mean "any number of `T`s", for instance type `T = (String, String)`, then varargs suffices.

```
object Test extends App {

  def f(g: (Int*) => Int) = g(1,2,3)

  def sum(is: Int*) = is.sum

  Console println f(sum _)

  def f2(g: (Int*) => Int, h: =>Seq[Int]): Int = g(h: _*)

  Console println f2(sum _, List(1,2,3))

  def f3(g: (Int*) => Int, is: Int*): Int = g(is: _*)

  Console println f3(sum _, 1,2,3)
}
```

Comment: I've seen this. I don't mean "any number of `T`s" though. I mean any number of anything, be it `String`, `boolean`, `Int`, ...

Comment: @MeredithLeu I kind of figured when your answer popped up, which is why I was too lazy that night to format my answer, but thanks to petr-pudlak for doing that.

Comment: Users are automatically notified about comments on questions with their name in them, afaik. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if your functions take a variable number of arguments. This is needed because they don't know in advance how many arguments will the action supply to them. As others mentioned, a variadic function is translated as a function whose last argument is a sequence. So you can do something like this:

```
case class Action[T](f: (String, Seq[T]) => Boolean);

def testfn(s: String, args: Int*): Boolean = true;

new Action[Int](testfn _);
```

---

And if you need your functions to signal that they got a wrong number of arguments, you can let them return `Option` and perhaps add some helper functions for various arities, like

```
case class Action[T](f: (String, Seq[T]) => Option[Boolean]);
```

Then you can have helpers for different arities that convert a "normal" function into a variadic one returning `None` if it's given a wrong number of arguments:

```
// for 1 argument functions:
def toVar[T](f: (String, T) => Boolean)(s: String, xs: Seq[T]): Option[Boolean] =
  Some(xs).collect({ case Seq(x1) => f(s, x1) });
// for 2 argument functions:
def toVar[T](f: (String, T, T) => Boolean)(s: String, xs: Seq[T]): Option[Boolean] =
  Some(xs).collect({ case Seq(x1, x2) => f(s, x1, x2) });

def testfn(s: String, x1: Int, x2: Int): Boolean =
  (x1 == x2);

new Action[Int](toVar(testfn _));
```

You could even avoid `toVar` if you created specialized constructors for `Action` for different arities that just call `toVar` and the main constructor.

Comment: thanks for the update, btw, see comment to my answer. SO doesn't let me send a msg to whom I wish to send it.